# Select count from datatable against dynamic query

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have a data set in memory which has two data tables in it.

- Cont
- Ins

Secondly i have separate data table (in memory) in which i have rows in following format.

And suppose it has two rows. In actual it may have million of rows

```
ID    TableName    ColumnName    Operator    value 
1       Const        ID            =           1  
2       Ins         app_ID         =         558877
```

**As is**: Now i get information from given rows and construct a query and execute it in database server like:

```
Select count(*) from Cont.Id= 1 and Ins.app_id = 558877;
```

On the basis of above query result i have implemented my business logic.

**Objective:** In order to increase performance i want to execute query in application server as now i have complete table in memory. how can i do it.

**Note**: Tables name may vary according to data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to keep tables with millions of rows in memory?

In terms of counting an in memory table, how is it kept? If it's a datatable as per your tag you can use the `DataTable.Rows.Count` property.

If your table names aren't known, you can loop over the tables in DataSet.Tables and call Rows.Count on each of them.

Comment: I don't want to count number of rows in data table. i want to execute count statement on two different tables based on query generated from given table.

Comment: No answer from genius peoples !. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create index on app_ID field. After that your count will run with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your query references undefined alias "Ins". You must specify another table in FROM/JOIN clause and change "count(*)" to "count(Cont.*)"